# iOS: Downloading xml/json to change how a game functions?

Tags: ios

I'm wondering if this violates Apples terms or not. Basically what I'm considering is essentially a way to mod a game. The app would be able to download a set of xml/json files from my server that would change things like say how many hitpoints a monster has or something like that. From what I can tell this is completely fine, however the part I'm not sure on is something like monster actions.

Lets say I wanted to give the ability for monsters to change how they react to something. So lets say in xml/json you could define something like oh an event where on monster hp change there is a 20% change to cast heal. That is sort of script but it would really just be raw data. The app on the iphone/ipad would execute it and you would not be able to insert any custom script only what the app allows.

Here is a really rough example of what I mean if that helps:

```
{
    event: {
        type: 'hpChange',
        range: '<50%',
        cast: {
            spell: 'heal',
            chance: .2
        }
    }
}
```

So essentially what this would mean is when the monsters hp changes, if its less than 50% there is a 20% chance to cast heal. So essentially is this something that would violate Apple's terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's okay. If this wasn't allowed, there would be no client-server applications in the app store. As long as the data you're transferring is not replacing the content with something illegal or violating any other terms, you should have no problem getting your application approved.